# Translate value of WFFM checkbox field in email

Tags: wffm

I'm currently setting up some Save Actions and 1 of them is 'Send Email Action'.
In the sent mail, the value of a checkbox field is always 'True' or 'False'.

Since it is a multilingual site, this needs to be translated properly.
Where can I configure this?

Comment: If my understanding is correct, you are going to translate the captured value into the email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override `Checkbox` class and add `Adapter` attribute. It's there in WFFM already. I have no idea why it's not used by default.

```
namespace WffmCustomization
{
    [Adapter(typeof(CheckboxAdapter))]
    public class Checkbox : Sitecore.Form.Web.UI.Controls.Checkbox
    {
    }
}
```

Set `Assembly` and `Class` fields of `/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Field Types/Simple Types/Checkbox` item to your `Checkbox` class:

[image]

Then add entries with `Key` set to `Selected` and `Not Selected` (camel case - important) in the language you need.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To get the translated value in the mail body, we added a processor in the `processMessage` pipeline.

```xml
<processMessage patch:source="Sitecore.Forms.config">
  <processor type="WFFM.Customization.SaveActions.EmailExt, WFFM.Customization" method="TranslateValues"/> 
</processMessage>
```

```csharp
public class EmailExt
{
    public EmailExt()
    { }

    public void TranslateValues(ProcessMessageArgs args)
    {
        // logic to translate
        foreach (AdaptedControlResult result in args.Fields)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We tested it. 1) It’s not possible to overwrite the value of the results you are looping (of type AdaptedControlResult). A workaround for this would be to set it by reflection using:
typeof(AdaptedControlResult).GetProperty("Value", BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).SetValue(result, value);
2) We're sending 2 mails when saving the form.
The first mail still contained true or false. It was only the second mail that contained the translated values, so something fishy with the events.